# Adjust two coordinates based on the distance between them

Tags: estimation, adjustment

I have two positions $\overline{X_1} \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, $\overline{X_2}\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the respectively measurement errors $\Sigma_{X_1}\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and $\Sigma_{X_2} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$. In addition I have the a measurement of the distance between the two positions using another measurement technique $\overline{r}\in \mathbb{R}$ with the error estimation $\sigma_r\in\mathbb{R}$

In addition I assume measurements are not correlated in any kind.

This means:

$\Sigma_{X_1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
                              a_1 & 0 \\ 
                              0 & a_2
                   \end{pmatrix}$ and $\Sigma_{X_2} = \begin{pmatrix} 
                              b_1 & 0 \\ 
                              0 & b_2
                   \end{pmatrix}$

I would like to adjust the system of the two positions $\overline{X_1}$ and $\overline{X_2}$ which the help of $\overline{r}$.

Concrete example, I have two position measured via two GPS' and their covariance matrix. In addition I have a distance measurement between the two point measured via radar.

I would like to fit or adjust the positions based on the relative distance between them.

How could I perform this iterative process?

Comment: What is the dimension of the space in which these "points" live and, if it's greater than one, what exactly are the $\Sigma_{*}$?  What kind of distance do you have in mind?  In what sense do you intend to iterate the adjustment?

Comment: @whuber, I updated the question. thanks for your feedback

Comment: Are $\bar{X}_1$,$\bar{X}_2$, and $\bar{r}$ observed values, i.e., some kind of noisy measurements of the positions of two objects and of the true distance? And you are looking to estimate the positions given these three measurements? If so, please edit the information into the question -- I'm guessing this interpretation but it's not clear.

Comment: I fixed your $\TeX$ markup, but left the mysterious phrase "nur inside them self" alone.  Would it be fair to interpret that as meaning the five random variables involved (components of the $X_i$ along with $r$) are independent?  Could you edit your post to clarify this?

Comment: I updated the question and gave a concrete example

Comment: Thank you.  I would suggest, then, *not* assuming the x and y coordinates are uncorrelated, because they often are correlated; and--if these measurements were taken at nearly the same time--you should not assume the two positional measurements are independent, because they definitely will not be.  These complications suggest that an approximate (rather than mathematically exact) solution would be acceptable, too.

Comment: @whuber, i agree with you, that the two coordinate in reality correlated, but I assume they not. Now is the question, assuming they are not correlated, how should I approach this problem.

Comment: The answers are going to be substantially different in the two cases. Assuming no correlation (which could be large and positive) will substantially reduce the influence of the distance measurement on the answer. Thus, your approach in ignoring the correlation seems--to stretch a point a bit--somewhat like asking "assuming dogs are fish, how fast can they swim?"  Although you can obtain an answer, its validity would be dubious.